# Take input from textBox2.text and int.Parse

Tags: c#

When I press the result button it returns an error instead of checking if the condition is OK or not.  It exits with the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

I'm trying to take input from the user and change it to an `int` in `textBox2`. Why does the application exit with an error?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "textBox1.Text";
        int qty = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
       
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 ||  qty == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Values");
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Thank You");
        }
    }
```

Comment: look up int.TryParse method as well as google the int.Parse Method to understand what it does... also what's purpose of this line `string name = "textBox1.Text";` also read up on the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` function

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(string.isNullOrWhitespace(textbox1.Text)       
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Values");
        return;
      }

   int qty = 0;
   if(!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out qty))        
       MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number value");        
   else
      MessageBox.Show("Thank you.");
}
```

If you're using a textbox for numerical input you should subscribe to the previewkeydown event and only accept numerical input, as typing in any other character will fail a tryparse.

Comment: The hyphen is a legitimate int character, depending on its location and frequency (and I don't know if there are other "negative" characters in other languages/cultures). Also integers have a max value. So subscribing to a key event isn't necessarily going to guarantee valid input. But it is a good start.

Comment: While I agree with everything you said, including the hyphen as part of numerical input would solve the first problem, and simply limiting the max characters of the input box would solve the second. I would personally prefer a NumericUpDown Control instead

Comment: Thank you all for your replay

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse something that is a blank string "" remember that is a empty string the compiler doesn't know that blank means zero (a number) because it's not. Like bill said you have to tell the text box to receive only numerical input built on Visual Studio.